# Pass data between threads using boost.signals2

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

I apologize for the ambiguous title, but I'll try to elaborate further here:

I have an application which includes (among others) a control, and TCP server classes.
Communication between the TCP and control class is done via this implementation:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>                                                                        

// T - Observable object type                                                                        
// S - Function signature                                                                            
template <class T, typename S> class observer {                                                      
        using F = std::function<S>;                                                                  

      public:                                                                                        
        void register_notifier(T &obj, F f)                                                          
        {                                                                                            
                connection_ = obj.connect_notifier(std::forward<F>(f));                              
        }                                                                                            

      protected:                                                                                     
        boost::signals2::scoped_connection connection_;                                              
};                                                                                                   

// S - Function signature                                                                            
template <typename S> class observable {                                                             
      public:                                                                                        
        boost::signals2::scoped_connection connect_notifier(std::function<S> f)                      
        {                                                                                            
                return notify.connect(std::move(f));                                                 
        }                                                                                            

      protected:                                                                                     
        boost::signals2::signal<S> notify;                                                           
};
```

Where the TCP server class is the observable, and the control class is the observer.

The TCP server is running on a separate thread from the control class, and uses boost::asio::async_read. Whenever a message is received, the server object sends a notification via the 'notify' member, thus triggering the callback registered in the control class, and then waits to read the next message.

The problem is that I need to somehow safely and efficiently store the data currently stored in the TCP server buffer and pass it to the control class before it's overridden by the next message.

i.e. :

```
inline void ctl::tcp::server::handle_data_read(/* ... */)                                  
{                                                                                                    
        if (!error) {                                                                                 
                /* .... */
                notify(/* ? */); // Using a pointer to the buffer
                                 // would obviously fail as it
                                 // is overridden in the next read                    
        }
        /* .... */                                                                                            
}
```

Those were my ideas for a solution so far:

1. Allocating heap memory and passing a pointer to it using
   unique_ptr, but I'm not sure if boost.signals2 is move-aware.
2. Use an
   unordered map (shared between the objects) that maps an integer index to a unique_ptr of the
   data type (`std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<data_type>>`),
   then only pass the index of the element, and 'pop' it in the control
   class callback, but it feels like an overkill.

What I'm really looking for is an idea for a simple and efficient solution to pass the TCP buffer contents for each message between the threads.

**Note** I'm also open for suggestions to redesign my communication method between the objects if it's completely wrong.

Comment: There is `std::future` and `std::promise` in modern C++ Standard Library.

Comment: In Qt you also can connect Signals and Slots living on different threads using a QueuedConnection, there are many examples around.